# How to call Observable after Subject next triggered

Tags: angular

In my service I have a subject which is triggered when method called.

```
    export class AuthService {
        isAdmin$ = new Subject();
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        private utilService: UtilService) {
       }
    
      login(user:User){
          this.isAdmin$.next();
        return this.http.post(url, user);
}

    isAdmin(){
         return this.http.get(`url/permissions`));
      }
    }
```

In my component I'm subscribing on this subject. And I want to call another method which returns Observable. But if I call it like this inside my component, it's not working.

```
this.authService.isAdmin$.subscribe(()=>{
    this.authService.isAdmin().subscribe((result)=>{
      this.isAdmin = result;
    });
```

So how do I call method, which returns Observable after Subject next triggered?

Comment: what does `isAdmin()` do?

Comment: I dont really understand what you want to do. What is isAdmin() ?

Comment: Can u please share the missing pieces? Or create a stack-blitz. 

Subscribe inside subscribe is always a bad practice

Comment: I have added missing method.

Comment: I guess your isAdmin() method, must  be called after your login() method, right ?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [SwitchMap or SwitchMapTo](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) :

```
this.authService.isAdmin$
  .pipe(
    switchMapTo(this.authService.isAdmin())
  ).subscribe(result => this.isAdmin = result);
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. This is what i want! It works great.

Comment: Yeeah great ! :)